# how multi language urls works in django?

Tags: python, django

I want to design a multi language website in django. To determine language I want to use urls like:

```
site.com/en/poll, site.com/en/blog/, site.com/in/blog, site.com/in/poll.
```

in site urls file I use:

```
url(r'^(?P<lang>)/blog/', include('blog.urls')),
```

The lang parameter should be passed to view so I can grab English posts. but it goes to 404.What should I do?

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the regex for the `lang` group:

```
url(r'^(?P<lang>[a-z]{2})/blog/', include('blog.urls')),
```